# Generic structure to transfer from 32 bit machine to 64 bit machine

Tags: c

We use the below structure in code running on a 32-bit machine.  If we have to transfer this stucture to a 64-bit machine, is there any change required?

```
   struct test
   {
     int num;
     char a;
     double dd;
   };
```

i have two machine on network and i have two transfer data stored in above mention structure from 32 bit machine to 64 bit machine so how to make the above mention structure in generic structure so that data will not loose... this is my question.

Comment: It depends on how you use it. Int size will probably change, but it is not an issue unless you depend you code on its size

Comment: If you want the same int size, you could use `int32_t`.

Comment: It also depends on what "transfer this structure" means.  If you just intend to recompile the code for the 64-bit environment, then there's nothing inherent in that structure that would prevent the resulting program from working correctly.  If you're talking about transferring *data* between a 32-bit machine and a 64-bit machine via binary I/O, however, then you probably do need changes.

Comment: @John  i have two machine on network and i have two transfer data stored in above mention structure from 32 bit machine to 64 bit machine so how to make the above mention structure in generic structure so that data will not loose... this is my question.

Comment: @Avishi Please edit your question and add all such clarifications there.

Comment: Structure padding could have any imapct?

Answer (score 3):

The layout of such a structure is completely platform-dependent and you can't even use it to transfer data between two instances of a 32 bit application compiled using different compilers, or different compile settings under the same compiler.

The only safe use for such a structure in data transfer is between multiple instances of the same executable. Same as in: same build. You can't even generally guarantee that some later build will have the same structure.

To transfer binary data in a binary-compatible fashion, you need to use some kind of a binary stream that maintains a fixed binary structure, independent of the platform. Google Protocol Buffers are one example of such, another is Qt's `QDataStream`.

Comment: It's also not too hard to roll one's own data transfer protocol if only a small number of specific cases need to be supported.

Comment: @JohnBollinger As a general rule, "rolling one's own [x]" is a bad idea when a library exists to do the same. If it's a small personal project that you *know* will never get any bigger, then maybe. But in most cases writing something yourself risks needing to change it if you find out you actually want more features later. Plus a well-written library should be much easier than doing it yourself.

Comment: @zstevart : Depends on what environment the existing code operates in. If it depends on frameworks which have solutions for it, obviously the best is to use those solutions. If there is nothing serving the purpose along the existing depencies, it needs consideration whether it is a good idea to introduce another dependency. This can only be answered by an overall analysis, to see whether the current program tries to implement many features which would be provided by framework X or Y, to make the right long term decision.

Comment: @zstewart, certainly there is a relative cost assessment that should be performed whenever presented the alternatives of implementing a behavior directly or relying on a third-party library for it.  Often relying on the existing library will indeed be the best option, but there are a great many factors that can enter the equation, and the cases where rolling one's own win out are by no means as limited as you depict.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the struct is not really adequate to use for network or persistency purposes, as it relies in too many ways on the C implementation (compiler + platform).

"Transferring" depends on what you're doing with the struct and contained elements.

These items should be on you checklist:

- Check elements for value ranges. All used types *may* change in width. `char` may change in signedness.
- Check the whole structure's size. This might be important for code relying on a specific size or some arbitrary bounds.
- When leaving the process's address space (network or persistently storing) make sure that the struct's are properly migrated, incl. endings, size, alignment.

Everything depends heavily on the used C implementations on the different platforms.